# Is there a Python Package to support MySQL with Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, pycharm, mysql-connector

so I was just wondering. I am designing this Kivy app but I currently use .txt files which is messy and just seems like a huge waste of time. I was wondering if there was a package that could read/write/create MySQL databases with python. However, I do use Pycharm and I read a while back that the free version *the one I use*. May have some limitations with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `mysql` package for this.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html

The PyCharm support for MySQL is just for viewing the data in the database as a programmer or for debugging.

Comment: Hey I got an error when installing 
'''Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-ec23h849/mysqlclient/'''
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you followed these steps? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-binary.html

Comment: No, I didn't. Followed steps. Worked perfectly. Thank you!